# Python character multiply or list multiply

Tags: python

```
a1 = 'a'*5
a2 = ''.join(['a']*5)
```

Say if I had the two variables above. Just wondering which one is more efficient or is of better practice to use.

Thanks!

Comment: The one without an extra list wrapper and method call.

Answer (score 3):

The first is obviously better practice -- it expresses your actual intent more clearly.

Let's find out which is more efficient, using `ipython`'s `%timeit` function:

```
In [1]: %timeit a1 = 'a'*5
10000000 loops, best of 3: 14.6 ns per loop

In [2]: %timeit a1 = ''.join(['a']*5)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 326 ns per loop

In [3]: 326/14.6
Out[3]: 22.328767123287673
```

So, by a factor of more than 20 times, the first is faster, on my machine. Your result, of course, may vary.

Ps. Of crouse `a1 = 'aaaaa'` might be the best choice of all.

Comment: Re your p.s.: yes, if the number of `a`'s is known when you are writing your program...

Answer (score 2):

I'll go for the first one in any case:

> Zen 3: Simple is better than complex.

Comment: Absolutely agree with the message of this answer. Unless the code section is critical for performance, stick to the simplest expression even if it might be a bit slower. However, in this case the second method is both needlessly complex and slower.